What do the codes on this production pencil drawing from Phineas and Ferb mean?
I recently acquired this production pencil drawing from Disney's Phineas and Ferb. I don't know much about the TV animation pipeline from this era, so I'm curious about the codes found in the various parts of the drawing - what were they used for and what do these ones mean?


An interesting question..the ones in the bottom right at PF 12E. Phineas and Ferb Episode 12, maybe?

The codes in several of these rough production drawings for television series seem to follow a similar pattern, even across studios (compare it, for example, with this drawing and the ones in the table below):

upper right: frame number (#F) and additional information about the placement within the sequence;
centre right: the pose (POSE#) (when the drawing contains more characters, there might additional specifications, e.g. here);
lower right: scene (SC), background (BG), series episode;
lower left: production code/item number/unique identification code (here it's a compound of the individual numbers found in the lower right) (often accompanied by a stamp of the production company and a production code, possibly only applied once they are intended for sale).




code
interpretation




11F2S1W (IIFLSIW/11FLS(u)?)
The first part is likely the frame number (11F). I'm guessing the rest has to do with the layer (as different cels may be superimposed) and the position of this frame within the sequence of frames/storyboard, and perhaps movement cues.


POSE1
The pose used for the character(s) (initially I thought it read "post", but similar images use "pose").


SC1e
Scene 1e


S/A BG 6
Background #6 (as this is a drawing of the animated foreground) (S/A = same as?)


PF12e
Phineas & Ferb episode 12/season 1, episode 2


DOAA B0850
I think this is an abbreviation for the Disney studio it was produced at or for (Disney O? Animation Art), but I can't find any references apart from writings on other production drawings and cels. It can also be seen here, here, and here, where it's referred to as its "SKU #".



Note that this is mostly guesswork based on some (limited) knowledge of the process and similar drawings and their descriptions.
